# Replacing variables in Python

Tags: python, variables

This is my script:

```
fruit  = "apple"
phrase = "I like eating " + fruit + "s."

def say_fruit(fruit):
    print phrase

say_fruit('orange')
```

I'm trying to get `say_fruit` to use the string given inside the `phrase` variable, which actually uses the variable already assigned before to it (`apple`). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `phrase` is bound to a string when the module loads and is never changed. You need to be dynamic, like this:

```
def phrase(fruit):
    return "I like eating " + fruit + "s."

def say_fruit(fruit):
    print phrase(fruit)
```

Globals are just a bad idea that will haunt you in the future. Resist the temptation to use them.

Comment: Running that gave me `<function phrase at 0x0000000001DA8518>`. What's this?

Comment: No it does not. Try again, but make sure you copy/paste the code from the question.

Comment: You forgot to add () at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is this, right?

```
>>> say_fruit('orange')
I like eating oranges.
>>> say_fruit('apples')
I like eating apples.
```

If so, move the definition of phrase into the function. The end result should be something like:

```
def say_fruit(fruit):
    phrase = "I like eating " + fruit + "s."
    print phrase

say_fruit('orange')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run this line of code

```
phrase = "I like eating " + fruit + "s."
```

Python automatically substitutes `'apple'` for `fruit` and `phrase` becomes `" I like eating apples."`.

I prefer using `.format()` to do this, as it preserves readability:

```
fruit  = "apple"
phrase = "I like eating {fruit}s."

def say_fruit(fruit):
    print phrase.format(fruit=fruit)

say_fruit('orange')
```

`.format()` substitutes `{var}` with the contents of `var` when called.